# randomizer only generating up to 99 c++

Tags: c++

So I am trying to generate 10,000 random numbers from 1-100, but it is only generating up to 99 numbers because when I display it I can only see from 1-99, unless it is my code for finding it. What is happening in my code is i am trying to find how many times the number is generated. Basically a frequency/histogram.

EDIT:I am generating 100, but its not displaying, i get a error
Here is my code:

```
vector<int> vint;

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    int x = (rand() % 100) + 1;
    vint.push_back(x);
}

frequency(vint);

void frequency (vector<int> v1)
{
int counter = 1;
int max = 0;
int mode = v1[0];
int numbercheck = 0;
for (int pass = 0; pass < 10000-1 ; pass++)
{
    if (v1[pass] == v1[pass + 1])
    {
        counter++;
        numbercheck++;

    }
    else
    {
        cout << v1[pass] << ": " << counter << "..................." << endl;
        counter = 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me just that rand() might not have generated 99 and thus your addition of 1 may not have worked. Please increase size and see if you get a 100. Oops! For loop is outside function for generation.

Comment: Remember `rand()` isn't very random, so if you need cryptographically random numbers you might want to use a better generator. You should get values in the range of 0-99 with that code, +1 should offset it to 1-100, but rolling 100 is a 1 in 100 event. Are you sure you're generating enough data to be sure you're never getting 100? Have you tested the distribution of your random function?

Comment: Your code does not compile, but you could easily have written it to make a self-contained, minimal, working example. Please edit your code so that it can be run without modification.

Comment: There is a non-zero probability that 1000 random values in the range [1,100] will not contain any 100's.

Comment: Making your code compilable and running it does show the number 100 being generated for me. Here's an example output from where I've changed the output to show how many times each number is generated. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rwXoaXnqCbm9GOp6

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `c++11` compatible compiler then avoid using `rand()` and use the Mersenne-Twister engine instead for higher quality random sequences. Here is a code snippet example:

```
#include <random>

int main(void) {
     std::random_device rd; // for random seed
     std::seed_seq seed{rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd(), rd()};
     std::mt19937 eng(seed);

     const int min = 1;
     const int max = 100;

     // used to generate ints in interval [min,max] (inclusive)
     std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(min,max); 

     int randomInt = dist(engine); // generate random int using dist and mtengine

     return 0;

}
```

See this (entertaining) video for some reasons on why `rand()` is bad:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: That's a much better approach to things. Nice!

Comment: How did you determine that `rand()` was the culprit in the OP's code?

Comment: This of course doesn't really answer the question, but it shows the right way to generate random numbers.

Comment: @PeteBecker I didn't determine that, I was simply providing a better way to produce random numbers of higher quality than using `rand()`.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury - so this "answer" doesn't even pretend to address the problem that the question is about.

Comment: @PeteBecker This answer will definitely produce random integers in the interval required in the question so it does provide a correct solution.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury - since you didn't determine that `rand()` was causing the problem (and the EDIT makes it clear that the problem had **nothing** to do with `rand()`), "replace `rand()`" is cargo-cult programming, not engineering.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm not trying to insinuate that my answer solved the exact problem in the question, but it does provide a solution which just so happens to be far better than the current question implementation. If you have an issue with this then flag my answer, it's no skin off my nose.

Answer (score 0):

You should accept ArchBishop's answer. Here is a simpler program for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vint;

    for(int i=0; i<10000; ++i)
    {
        vint.push_back(rand()%100 + 1);
    }

    for(const auto&e: vint)
        cout << e << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It generated 100 for me but might not generate for you.

Comment: No, he should not accept ArchBishop's answer, since neither it nor this code solves the problem (as edited...).

Comment: His code will not compile as for loop seems out of place which was my first comment to the question. This code is just to exemplify.